# Как правильно:ООШ или оош

Tags: грамотная-речь

Нарушение выявлено в кабинете информатики МБОУ Алтунинская оош или МБОУ Алтунинской оош. Кстати, оош -с прописной или строчной?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> МБОУ Алтунинская оош

Правильно:

***МБОУ "Алтунинская ООШ".***

**P.S.**

Название в кавычках -- не склоняется.

Comment: Это если название в кавычках, а когда без кавычек (так в уставе), то надо изменять?. А почему оош с большой буквы, это же не аабревиатура, а просто первые буквы (типа вуз)

Comment: ООШ -- аббревиатура. Может, когда-нибудь и будет писаться строчными, как и "вуз", но пока -- прописными. === Что же до "так в уставе"... К сожалению, и в уставах бывают ошибки.

Comment: Как раз вуз является в своем роде исключением - это аббревиатура, которая стала (считается) словом, поэтому и пишется с маленькой буквы. А в роли аббревиатуры нужно было бы писать прописными - ВУЗ. Справочная служба грамоты.ру: "По общему правилу инициальные аббревиатуры пишутся прописными: ВАК, ПТУРС. Исключения единичны, в их числе как раз слово вуз, а также дот, дзот; возможно написание строчными аббревиатуры загс (при наличии и варианта ЗАГС). Написание таких аббревиатур строчными связано с многолетней традицией их употребления."

Comment: А как быть с названием без кавычек: Нарушение выявлено в кабинете информатики МБОУ Алтунинская ООШ или МБОУ Алтунинской ООШ?

Answer (score 0):

Я почитал обсуждения к ответу slava1947. Не буду повторять.

Я уставах может быть сколько угодно ошибок. Но исправлять (да еще в текстах, претендующих на официоз) простым смертным не дано.

Но из этого подхода следует не только отсутствие кавычек, но и невозможность склонения. Ведь если бы склонение предполагалось авторами уставного названия, оно бы и в исходной форме присутствовало. Аналогично и с заглавными буквами. Все должно быть как в уставе.

Так что написание "в кабинете информатики *МБОУ Алтунинская оош*" выглядит меньшим из всех зол, хотя и не совсем по-русски получается. Вот все название (то, что у меня курсивом) можно бы закавычить - тоже не совсем по правилам, но для некоторого удобства восприятия. Раз такое хитрое название придумали, путь оно и будет названием, все вместе. Типа что-то там с названием "МБОУ ... оош". Иначе тут даже видимость русского языка не соблюсти. Другой вопрос, надо ли к этому стремиться вопреки буквоедскому правилу незыблемости уставного названия. Так что смотрите, или

**в кабинете информатики *МБОУ Алтунинская оош***
(курсив в этом случае желательно сохранить).

или

**"в кабинете информатики "МБОУ Алтунинская оош"**

Ничего другого рекомендовать не могу.