# как склоняется название образовательной организации

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, как склоняются названия школ. Название без кавычек. Например, нарушения были выявлены в МБОУ Яковцевская ООШ или в МБОУ Яковцевской ООШ? Всегда считала, что если название без кавычек, то изменяется все(в муниципальном бюджетном образовательном учреждении Яковцевской ООШ). И почему ООШ и СОШ с заглавной буквы? Спасибо

Comment: Послушайте, сколько можно спрашивать одно и то же?

Comment: Повтор

http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416214/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%A8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%88

Comment: Ответ не "тривиальный" а существенный.

Повтор

http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416214/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%A8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%88

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кавычки здесь всё-таки необходимы.

После инициальной аббревиатуры приложение (название школы) в кавычках всегда стоит в именительном падеже, что очень удобно для точного оформления названия учреждения в документах.

Родовое слово в аббревиатуре УЧРЕЖДЕНИЕ среднего рода, а слово ШКОЛА - женского. Это ещё одно условие постановки кавычек. Так что единственно верный вариант всё-таки ***в МБОУ "Яковцевская ООШ"***.

О больших буквах в аббревиатурах:

*Инициальные аббревиатуры пишутся прописными буквами: ООН, МИД, РФ. Точки или пробелы между буквами не ставятся, но между двумя самостоятельно употребляющимися аббревиатурами используется пробел: ИРЯ РАН, МИД РФ.
Слова, образованные от инициальных аббревиатур путем присоединения суффиксов, пишутся строчными буквами: эсэмэска (от СМС), кавээнщик (от КВН), гаишник (от ГАИ), мидовцы (от МИД). В иных случаях прописные буквы сохраняются: мини-КВН, СМС-рассылка.
Аббревиатуру **вуз** принято по традиции писать строчными буквами. Вариантное написание – у аббревиатуры ЗАГС  (**загс**).*  [Грамота.ру](http://%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8:%20%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%9D,%20%D0%9C%D0%98%D0%94,%20%D0%A0%D0%A4.%20%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F,%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB:%20%D0%98%D0%A0%D0%AF%20%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%9D,%20%D0%9C%D0%98%D0%94%20%D0%A0%D0%A4.%20%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0,%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2,%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8:%20%D1%8D%D1%81%D1%8D%D0%BC%D1%8D%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%20(%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%A1%D0%9C%D0%A1),%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8D%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA%20(%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%9A%D0%92%D0%9D),%20%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20(%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%93%D0%90%D0%98),%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%86%D1%8B%20(%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%9C%D0%98%D0%94).%20%D0%92%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F:%20%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%9A%D0%92%D0%9D,%20%D0%A1%D0%9C%D0%A1-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0.%20%D0%90%D0%B1%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83%20%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B7%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8.%20%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%E2%80%93%20%D1%83%20%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%97%D0%90%D0%93%D0%A1%20%20(%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%81).)

Answer (score 0):

Ладно, коли движок считает мои ответы тривиальным перенесу сюда полностью.
//================================
Я почитал обсуждения к ответу slava1947. Не буду повторять.

Я уставах может быть сколько угодно ошибок. Но исправлять (да еще в текстах, претендующих на официоз) простым смертным не дано.

Но из этого подхода следует не только отсутствие кавычек, но и невозможность склонения. Ведь если бы склонение предполагалось авторами уставного названия, оно бы и в исходной форме присутствовало. Аналогично и с заглавными буквами. Все должно быть как в уставе.

Так что написание "в кабинете информатики *МБОУ Алтунинская оош*" выглядит меньшим из всех зол, хотя и не совсем по-русски получается. Вот все название (то, что у меня курсивом) можно бы закавычить - тоже не совсем по правилам, но для некоторого удобства восприятия. Раз такое хитрое название придумали, путь оно и будет названием, все вместе. Типа что-то там с названием "МБОУ ... оош". Иначе тут даже видимость русского языка не соблюсти. Другой вопрос, надо ли к этому стремиться вопреки буквоедскому правилу незыблемости уставного названия. Так что смотрите, или

**в кабинете информатики *МБОУ Алтунинская оош***
(курсив в этом случае желательно сохранить).

или

**"в кабинете информатики "МБОУ Алтунинская оош"**

Ничего другого рекомендовать не могу.
//=============
[Как правильно:ООШ или оош](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416214/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%A8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%88)